# How to transform and map multiple json objects with nodejs?

Tags: arrays, api, request-promise

I am trying to transform and map/merge two endpoints with nodejs , I only know database now learning nodejs. I need assistance with the following using Nodejs and promises

data:

```
var a =  [ { farmer_revenue_id: 63,
      farmer_id: 518,
      activity_id: 0,
      revenue_type: 1,
      value_date: '2018-07-01',
      amount: '558.00',
      remarks: '',
      capture_date: '2018-07-17' }]
var b = [ { revenue_type_id: 1, name: 'Sale' }]
```

Transformations is done on the date and amount. we also replace the revenue type with revenue type name. lastly we omit some data which are not required.

expected output:

```
[ { farmer_revenue_id: 63,
  farmer_id: 518,
  activity_id: 0,
  revenue_type_name: sale,
  value_date: '2018/07/01',
  amount: $ 558.00,
  capture_date: '2018/07/17' }]
```

Comment: [Please make an attempt to solve this yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), and [show any research you may have done](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast workaround:

```js
let a = [{ 
  farmer_revenue_id: 63,
  farmer_id: 518,
  activity_id: 0,
  revenue_type: 1,
  value_date: '2018-07-01',
  amount: '558.00',
  remarks: '',
  capture_date: '2018-07-17' 
}];

let b = [{ 
    revenue_type_id: 1, 
    name: 'Sale' 
}];

a = a.reduce((reduced, aItem) => {
    const aItemClone = {...aItem};
    const foundB = b.find((bItem) =>
        bItem.revenue_type_id === aItemClone.revenue_type
    ) || null;

    if (foundB !== null)
        aItemClone.revenue_type_name = foundB.name;
    delete aItemClone.revenue_type;
    reduced.push(aItemClone);

    return reduced;
}, []);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thanks I think i see some light.

Comment: Hi dorintufar , can you assist me with using and api instead of the inline json ?

Comment: Hello @DagananalaTshipange, you need help to clarify usage of  "web api" or just javascript api?

Comment: using any api with the json object structure I provided for a and b.